# Heroku Laravel Voyager Amazon s3 "Image source not readable" on upload error

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, amazon-s3, voyager

Few days ago I started using laravel with voyager and deployed on heroku server. since heroku uses ephemeral filesystem so I was force to use amazon s3 services. The problem is whenever I upload a image on media manager in my voyager app it gives "Image source not readable" error message but at the same time shows images perfectly. I can only reproduce this error when I'm uploading a image/file or cropping a image. I thought this might be amazon policy issue but I've added policy to allow it still did not work.

**Block public access (bucket settings)**

```
Block all public access
Off
    Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)
    Off
    Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
    Off
    Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket policies
    Off
    Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket policies
    Off
```

**Bucket policy editor**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1************",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1************",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Image Upload Error Image:*

[image: Image Upload Error Image]

*Image Crop Error Image:*

[image: Image Crop Error Image]

## **EDIT 1**

So I debugged it in vendor directory and turns out it's Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException error in vendor\tcg\voyager\src\Http\Controllers\VoyagerMediaController.php

*vendor\tcg\voyager\src\Http\Controllers\VoyagerMediaController.php* file

```
public function crop(Request $request)
{
    // Check permission
    $this->authorize('browse_media');

    $createMode = $request->get('createMode') === 'true';
    $x = $request->get('x');
    $y = $request->get('y');
    $height = $request->get('height');
    $width = $request->get('width');

    $realPath = Storage::disk($this->filesystem)->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    $originImagePath = $realPath.$request->upload_path.'/'.$request->originImageName;

    $e = [];
    try {
        if ($createMode) {
            // create a new image with the cpopped data
            $fileNameParts = explode('.', $request->originImageName);
            array_splice($fileNameParts, count($fileNameParts) - 1, 0, 'cropped_'.time());
            $newImageName = implode('.', $fileNameParts);
            $destImagePath = $realPath.$request->upload_path.'/'.$newImageName;
        } else {
            // override the original image
            $destImagePath = $originImagePath;
        }

        Image::make($originImagePath)->crop($width, $height, $x, $y)->save($destImagePath);

        $success = true;
        $message = __('voyager::media.success_crop_image');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $success = false;
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        $errors['originImagePath'] = $originImagePath;
        $errors['destImagePath'] = $destImagePath;
        $errors['exception'] = get_class($e);
        $errors['file'] = $e->getFile();
        $errors['code'] = $e->getCode();
        $errors['line'] = $e->getLine();
        $errors['trace'] = $e->getTrace();
    }

    return response()->json(compact('success', 'message', 'errors'));
}
```

Post Response *http://localhost/voyager/public/admin/media/crop*

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Image source not readable",
  "errors": {
    "originImagePath": "//Capture1.PNG",
    "destImagePath": "//Capture1.cropped_1570987211.PNG",
    "exception": "Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException",
    "file": "D:\\wamp64\\www\\voyager\\vendor\\intervention\\image\\src\\Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDecoder.php",
    "code": 0,
    "line": 346
  }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: have you checked the Media-file permission on S3 , try to assign 777(-rwxrwxrwx) permissions and then try to access.